# Oozie to run job only in specified time frame

Tags: hadoop, sqoop, oozie

I need to sqoop in 600TB of data from RDBMS system and I have to do it in a particular time frame from midnight 12AM to morning 7AM. Since entire data cannot be ingested in a single day, need to perform in batches. Is it possible from oozie to terminate a job by 7AM and restart the failed job next day.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is no such feature in Oozie. I'd try to kill and start the job using oozie-cli and cron.